# Exclude project dependency from project dependency

Tags: gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

Given the following multi-module project, how can I avoid having duplicate dependency on D?

```
Module A
  compile project('B')
  compile project('C')
Module B
  compile project('D')
Module C
  compile project('D')
Module D
```

I've tried setting the project D dependency to transitive in B & C with:

```
   compile(project('D')) { transitive = false }
```

but I am still getting duplicate dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out this works just fine with just

```
compile project(':D')
```

It was failing for me because I actually had duplicate classes in the modules.